# Is it possible to initialize immutable variables with match in Rust?

Tags: variables, rust, immutability, mutability

I have this piece of code where I try to convert command line arguments to integers. The problem is, the variables width and height should really be immutable, as I don't plan to change them. Is there any way I can use match like `let width = {match....}` and initialize them in one step as immutable variables rather than giving them a default value and mutating them? I believe this would be safer and more efficient.

```
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let width_arg = &args[1];
let height_arg = &args[2];

let mut width = 0;
let mut height = 0;

match width_arg.parse::<i32>() {
    Ok(w) => width = w,
    Err(_) => ask_for_number(),
}

match height_arg.parse::<i32>() {
    Ok(h) => height = h,
    Err(_) => ask_for_number(),
}
```

Comment: You may be interested by https://github.com/TeXitoi/structopt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, match is an expression, so you should be able to rewrite it as follows:

```
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let width_arg = &args[1];
let height_arg = &args[2];

let width = match width_arg.parse::<i32>() {
    Ok(w) => w,
    Err(_) => ask_for_number(),
};

let height = match height_arg.parse::<i32>() {
    Ok(h) => h,
    Err(_) => ask_for_number(),
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just initialise the variable like so: `let a = match b { /* your code here*/ };`